# SVG rect goes to new position when wrapped in div with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am new to React, and I am having trouble with some formatting issues.

I have one react component, an SVG that is the background element. On it, I am trying to render several points, with annotations when you hover.

I am able to get the points to show when I simply return the point directly, but I need to wrap it in a div so I can add some text.

**Working**, rendering the point in the right place:

```
    class InfoPoint extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <rect x="10" y="93" width="15" height="12" rx="2" ry="2" fill="red" ></rect>
        );
      }
    }
```

**Not working**, I cannot find the element when I wrap it in the div:

```
   class InfoPoint extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="point">
          <rect x="10" y="93" width="15" height="12" rx="2" ry="2" fill="red" ></rect>
         </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: It would help massively if you included the rest of your relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<rect>` elements must be inside an `<svg>` element. And `<div>` elements are invalid inside a `<svg>` element.  You can't indiscriminately mix HTML and SVG elements together.

Comment: yes, i was able to accomplish my goal by wrapping in SVG tags like mentioned and just rendering my text inside using <text> tags, however, I still cannot seem to figure out why a div placed in there goes to a different location than an SVG element.

Comment: Well I can't really offer a guess on that because you haven't posted enough of the code & SVG to work with.